# getArguments() in Activity Class?

Tags: java, android

I'm still learning AS & java and recently bought an app code but it has "getArguments()" inside of fragment which I'd like to convert it into activity. Help is appreciated.

This is the code :

```
  String weburl = getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
    String data = getArguments().containsKey(LOAD_DATA) ? getArguments().getString(LOAD_DATA) : null;
    if (data != null) {
        browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(weburl, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
    } else {
        browser.loadUrl(weburl);
    }
```

How do I write the same code in an activity?

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is how to send info to an Activity, for that you need Intents
Please verify this info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Basically:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra message";
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);        
String message = "Hello this is an intent";    
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

To retrieve that data you have to do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

I invite you to check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java

Answer (score 2):

Intent extras are the activity equivalent of fragment arguments.

Comment: I fixed it by adding bundle but now have java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array error :/

Comment: So one activity will create an Intent and put some extras in it, then call startActivity() and pass in in the intent.  Another activity will use getIntent() to get a reference to the intent that the other activity prepared and can pull out the various extras.  As long as same names were used to put and get the extras, it should work.